# Remove text on WooCommerce Shop Page for Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a woocommerce storefront for a client that has a custom-built theme (by someone else) and for the life of me cannot find where I need to go to remove the subtext over the product preview on the main Shop page (the "at vero...")

See below:
[image]

Inspect element shows:
[image]

When I went into the `wc-template-functions.php` file I found the `product_loop` but there is nothing in here that I see generating the paragraph below the product title. Before I write some css to locate the `<p>` child element under parent `woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link` - is there someone within WC functions I can locate this? The product has no categories or tags as I thought this could be where it was coming from. My Google searches have resulted in nothing specific to what I'm looking to change on the shop page, just changes to the product page which I do not need.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply hide using CSS instead of change in core files